# How to prevent Volume Up button click when bluetooth remote shutter is clicked?

Tags: javascript, android, bluetooth

I am using bluetooth remote shutter in my javascript code to take selfie on Android browser.
My bluetooth shutter simulates a press on Keycode 13. So in javascript I can get keypress event and check keyCode is 13 or not. But the problem is it also returns volume up press. Every time when I click the shutter, Smartphone system's volume bar is shown and volumes up.
Is there anyway to prevent it? 
Any suggestions? 
or should I have to write some native android app which runs in background?

Any help is appreciated!

Best regards,

Mudin

Comment: AFAIK javascript cannot handle system level commands.I don't know much of android but basically system messages are a bunch of bitstreams.Bitstream send by shutter has some extra bits in addition to Keycode 13 since js interpreter cannot understand such heigher commands it essentialy applies a filter(binary based) which gives keycode 13 but android   system does understands it well and you see volume notification

Comment: @Novice Thank you for your answer, I got it. I will try to find other way, not javascript. Also in IOS it is returning keycode 115, not 13